# mysql_fetch_array returns an array with a value for the numeric index, but blank for the corresponding associative index

Tags: php, mysql

i have a table with the following fields:

```
row_id    
first_field
second_field
```

row_id is of type integer, is set to auto increment and is the primary key. the other two fields are of type text.

the table is populated up to five rows. as such, the values for row_id are 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5.

i also have another table of a similar structure that has a one-to-many correspondence with my first table.

something weird happens though when i do a select query and feed the result to mysql_fetch_array.

when i run this:

```
$query = "select a.*, b.* from table1 as a
         left join table2 as b on a.row_id = b.row_id";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($row); echo '</pre>';
}
```

i get this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [row_id] => 1
    [1] => some text
    [first_field] => some text
    [2] => some text
    [second_field] => some text 
}


Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [row_id] => 2
    [1] => some text
    [first_field] => some text
    [2] => some text
    [second_field] => some text 
}


Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [row_id] => 
    [1] => some text
    [first_field] => some text
    [2] => some text
    [second_field] => some text 
}


Array
(
    [0] => 4
    [row_id] => 
    [1] => some text
    [first_field] => some text
    [2] => some text
    [second_field] => some text 
}


Array
(
    [0] => 5
    [row_id] => 
    [1] => some text
    [first_field] => some text
    [2] => some text
    [second_field] => some text 
}
```

on each array result, i'd like to direct your attention to the first field, row_id. in the first two arrays, index 0 and row_id have the same values, whereas in the subsequent three arrays, only index 0 has a value. row_id appears to be null.

this is the first time i've ever encountered something like this. what is causing this? how can this be fixed?

thanks!

Comment: Could you add the query to your question please

Comment: You say the table is `row_id` yet your array references `thread_id`. Confuse.

Comment: ok, will edit the original question and include the query. thanks

Comment: @blake: sorry, a typo. i meant row_id. will edit. thanks

Comment: Do you get the same problem with `mysql_fetch_assoc()`?

Comment: @DaveRandom: yes, it's the same with mysql_fetch_assoc().

Comment: Be explicit about cols you're selecting instead of `a.*, b.*`. Since both tables have `row_id`, the fetch call is overwriting array keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to the fact that you have `LEFT JOIN`ed the other table in the query.

With a `LEFT JOIN`, the rows in the first table that do not have matching row in the second table will have the `JOIN`ed fields populated with `NULL` values.

Because you have a column called `row_id` in both tables and you have selected `*` from both tables, the later value for `row_id` is overwriting the earlier in the results. It would seem that there are no matching rows in `table2` for rows 3, 4 and 5 in `table1`. This is resulting in a NULL `row_id`.

The solution is to choose which `row_id` you want, and there are a number of ways to do this. But with a relatively simple set of results like this, I suggest you explicitly state all the columns you want:

```
SELECT a.*, b.col_1, b.col_2
FROM table1 a
LEFT JOIN table2 b ON a.row_id = b.row_id
```

Alternatively, you could drop the `LEFT` from the join, and the rows 3, 4 and 5 will be omitted from the results.